# Inclusive gateway JOIN behavior

Tags: bpmn

[image]

In the above process, what happens if:

1. A and B activates
2. OR-JOIN should now be waiting for 2 tokens
3. A completes
4. OR-JOIN now waits for B
5. B chooses exit 2
6. **Does OR-JOIN now understand that it no longer needs to wait for B? And continue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a tricky one. My initial thoughts were that this process would not finish if the second token went towards the **end2** end event. However, the BPMN specification does not seem to clearly define this case. The only relevant reference about inclusive gateways that I could find in the Specification is that

> Upon execution, a token is consumed from each incoming Sequence Flow
> that **has** a token. (BPMN Specification, Version 2, January 2011,
> page 435. My emphasis).

The word “has” raised some doubts in me and I found the following example in a BPMN book (Thomas Allweyer, BPMN 2.0), where the authors says that the converging inclusive gateway only waits for the tokens that **can** reach it and not necessarily all tokens that were created by a diverging inclusive gateway. That would also be in line with the formulation in the BPMN specification.

[image]

So in answer to your question, the “OR-JOIN” would indeed understand that it does not have to wait for the second token. The first token would be consumed by **end1** and the second token by **end2** and the process finishes normally.